# jQuery: click is not working in Safari & IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have been using `add_this_button_twitter` class for an element to share Twitter posts.
I need to trigger this popup in page load. I have tried to use `$('#element').click()` & `$('#element').trigger('click')`. But not worked in `Safari` & `IE`.

I have started to use the following code. Got the result in `Safari` 4 alone.

```
var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
theEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var element = document.getElementById('tweetlink');
element.dispatchEvent(theEvent);
```

Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

May be better to use [AddThis API](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365497-addthis-javascript-events#.Uon2GWSD5hc) in javascript?

Comment: Thanks Pinal. But I need Twitter Share alone. Please advice me.

Comment: Try this `theEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);` instead of your `theEvent.initMouseEvent`

Comment: $('#tweetlink').click();
var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
theEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
var element = document.getElementById('tweetlink');
element.dispatchEvent(theEvent);

Comment: I mean html+javascript example :) But it doesn't metter. For IE use `fireEvent` like this - if (document.createEventObject){ element.fireEvent('onclick', evt) } else{ element.dispatchEvent(evt); }

Comment: Can you please advice me to do twitter share using javascript?